# If None != 0 then how this condition passing

Tags: python

Can not able to understand, if None is not equals to zero,then how the below if condition is passing?

```
>>> None == 0
False
>>> if not None:
...   print ("1")
...
1
>>>
>>> None == False
False
>>>
```

Comment: Because you used `if not`?

Comment: and `None` is always false.

Comment: `bool(0) == bool(None)` ...

Comment: **Comparing** a value (to a number (or any value)) and **converting** a value to a different type (boolean) are two very different operations.

Comment: `None` is not false, added some more code in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many things in python which are considered 'falsy' when used in  a boolean context (like an if statement or with boolean operators like `and`, `not`, `or`, etc).

Specifically None, False, any numerical data type which compares equal to `0`, or any type which implements `__len__` and for which `len(container) == 0`.

For more information consider:

```
>>> bool(False)
False
>>> bool(0)
False
>>> bool([])
False
>>> bool('')
False
>>> bool(None)
False
>>> not None
True
>>> not 0
True
>>> not False
True
>>> not ''
True
>>>
```

For more information see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)

Comment: The term you're looking for is "falsy".  Otherwise, spot on.

Answer (score 2):

Let's ask the python shell...

```
In [1]: None == 0
Out[1]: False

In [2]: not None
Out[2]: True

In [3]: None?
Type:        NoneType
String form: None
Namespace:   Python builtin
Docstring:   <no docstring>
```

So that might give you a hint why `None==0` is returning False. For further hint..

```
In [6]: i = 0

In [7]: i?
Type:        int
String form: 0
Docstring:
int(x=0) -> int or long
int(x, base=10) -> int or long
```

Armed with this information we could dig into python's truth system...

> The following values are considered false:
>
> None
>
> False
>
> zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0L, 0.0, 0j.

So yes, Both `None` and `0` is considered false for `if`/`while` conditionals, but that doesn't mean all things evaluates to "False"  are themselves equal. As some of them have different types, they are not equivalent.

So the bottom line is :

[1] Not everything evaluates to `False` in a `if`/`while` statement are themselves equal.

[2] The reason for this is Python's Type system

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> bool(None)
False
>>> bool(0)
False
>>> None == 0
False
>>> bool(None) == bool(0)
True
```

Comparisons in Python are typesafe*, which means even though 2 variables are both truthy (or not truthy) does not imply that their direct comparison returns true.

```
>>> type(None)
<class 'NoneType'>
>>> type(0)
<class 'int'>
```

*except that `False == 0` and `True == 1` are guaranteed and the `==` operator is overloadable.

Answer (score 0):

See [Truth Value Testing](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing) chapter in Python's docs.

> Any object can be tested for truth value, for use in an if or while condition or as operand of the Boolean operations below. The following values are considered false:
>
> - None
> - False
> - zero of any numeric type, for example, 0, 0L, 0.0, 0j.
> - any empty sequence, for example, '', (), [].
> - any empty mapping, for example, {}.
> - instances of user-defined classes, if the class defines a **nonzero**() or **len**() method, when that method returns the integer zero or bool value False. [1](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing)
>
> All other values are considered true — so objects of many types are always true.
>
> Operations and built-in functions that have a Boolean result always return 0 or False for false and 1 or True for true, unless otherwise stated. (Important exception: the Boolean operations or and and always return one of their operands.)

Comment: Answers should be self-contained. If the link breaks for whatever reason, your answer will be useless.

Comment: Makes sense. Added quote.